# Show a single entry from a MySQL db relevant to the id

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm pretty new to MySQL and php and I'm having trouble incorporating that into my website.

What I'm creating is a car sales website, which uses a database to show an inventory page of all the cars (I've got this working). What I then want to be able to do is on each entry there is an 'id' which is a link that brings you to a single page with more information about that car. I've tried numerous googling and for whatever reason it isn't working, returning the error 'data error'. I'm pretty sure its a relatively easy fix, but as I'm new to this I can't figure it out how to fix it. I guess its going wrong looking up the id relevant to data entry on the link, but I have no idea what to do next.

Below is my inventory.php page which shows all of the database entries, then there is a row entry called id that is my primary key which i want to use to link to the moredetails.php page.

I have 1 database called inventory with 1 table called cars.

---

inventory.php

```
<div id="text">

            <?php include("connect-db.php"); ?>

            <?php

                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars", $db);
                if (!$result) {
                die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                }


                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<div class="i-contain"><div class="i-right"><div class="i-manu">'; 
                echo $row[manufacturer]." ".$row[model]." </div> ";
                echo '<div class="i-mdetails">';
                echo "<a href=\"moredetails.php?id={$nt["id"]}\">$row[id]</a> </div>";
                echo '<div class="i-details">';
                echo $row[year]." <br /> ".$row[mileage]." <br /> ".$row[price]." <br /> ".$row[description]." </div></div>"; 
                echo '<div class="i-image">'; 
                echo '<img class="resize_inv" src=';
                echo $row[image]."  /></div></div> <br />";
                }
            ?>

        </div>
```

---

moredetails.php

```
<body>
<?php include("connect-db.php"); ?>
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$id = $_GET['id'];
if(! is_numeric($id))
{
echo "Data Error";
exit();
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id=" . intval($_GET["id"]), $db);
if(! $result)
{
die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo $row[manufacturer];
echo $row[model];
echo $row[year] . " <br /> " . $row[mileage] . " <br /> " . $row[price] . " <br /> " . $row[description] . " " . $row[image] . " ";
}
?>
</body>
```

---

I haven't pasted the code for my connection-db.php page as that appears to be working fine. But if you need it let me know.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Look at your generated html. Are you sure that in link `moredetails.php?id=`comes a number?

Comment: No, no number '.../moredetails.php?id='

Comment: from where do you get `{$nt["id"]}` ?

Comment: I changed {$nt["id"]} to <a href=moredetails.php?id=$row[id]>$row[id]</a>. Which now puts the relevant id on the link. But now it comes up with this error for each field entry ' Notice: Use of undefined constant manufacturer - assumed 'manufacturer' in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/st/an/we/stanwellcars.co.uk/public_html/moredetails.php on line 48
ford'

Comment: You need to use `$row['COLUMN_NAME']`. Put th single quotes `'` around each column name.

Comment: if you are new to using PHP and MySQL, you should start off on the right foot and NOT use `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated and will be removed from PHP.  COnsider using mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
echo "<a href=\"moredetails.php?id={$nt["id"]}\">$row[id]</a> </div>";
```

Replace `"` in `$nt["id"]` to `'`:

```
echo "<a href=\"moredetails.php?id={$nt['id']}\">$row[id]</a> </div>";
```

Comment: I did try that and it didn't work. Changed the {$nt["id"]} to $row[id] and it redirects me. But now generates an 'undefined contrant' error as i've pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i'm allowed to answer my own question but I fixed it!

Thanks u_mulder as your comment prompted me to check my code.

I changed {$nt["id"]} in this string of code

```
echo "<a href=\"moredetails.php?id={$nt["id"]}\">$row[id]</a> </div>";
```

to

```
echo "<a href=moredetails.php?id=$row[id]>$row[id]</a> </div>";
```

this fixed the linking id issue.

but then generated this message:
Notice: Use of undefined constant manufacturer - assumed 'manufacturer' in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/st/an/we/stanwellcars.co.uk/public_html/moredeta‌​ils.php on line 48 ford

i fixed this error by putting each field entry into single quotes 
e.g $row[manufacturer]; 
$row['manufacturer'];

All is now working perfectly. Thanks.